# Change app theme styles programmatically on button click

Tags: java, android, xml, themes

I'm trying to create themes for my app and I'm running into some trouble. I have my styles in my values/styles.xml and I'm trying to change programmatically on button click. the problem is that when I change the theme its applying my toolbar styles to the actual activity. I understand its probably because im changing my themes with `Activity.setTheme();`. I was wondering what I would use if I wanted to apply the `setTheme` to a toolbar.

Here's my code:

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/app_theme</item>
</style>

<!-- Customize your theme here. -->
<style name="CustomToolbarStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:toolbarStyle">@style/CustomToolbarStyleMusic</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/app_theme</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/toolbar_music_theme</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/simple_back_white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="toolbar_music">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_theme</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">-90dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginEnd">-80dp</item>
</style>

<style name="toolbar_notes" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/app_theme</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">25dp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomToolbarStyleMusic" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/toolbar_music_theme</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/toolbar_music_theme</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseDrawable">@drawable/simple_back_white</item>
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeStyle">@style/MyTheme</item>
</style>

<!-- menu item theme -->
<style name="CustomPopUpStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">right</item>
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">-4dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@drawable/simple_brown_tile</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/black</item>

</style>

<style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBarStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTheme.ActionBar.TitleTextStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Utilities.java

```
private static int sTheme;
public final static int THEME_MAIN = 0;
public final static int THEME_NOTEBOOK = 1;

public static void changeToTheme(Activity activity, int theme) {
    sTheme = theme;
    activity.finish();
    activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, activity.getClass()));
}

public static void onActivityCreateSetTheme(Activity activity) {
    switch (sTheme) {
        default:
        case THEME_MAIN:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.CustomToolbarStyleMusic);
            break;
        case THEME_NOTEBOOK:
            activity.setTheme(R.style.CustomToolbarStyle);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to call `Activity.setTheme(int)` in the activity's `onCreate`, before `super.onCreate`. if I remember.

Comment: @NicolasMaltais I have it functioning to where it changes themes already, the problem I'm having is its applying my toolbar styles to the MainActivity, I want it to be applied to the toolbar